# What were Bertrand Russell's later views on quantum mechanics?

Tags: history-of-philosophy, quantum-physics, bertrand-russell, history

Russell touched on QM a bit in The Analysis of Matter, which was the same year as the Fifth Solvay Conference. I am sure he must have thought very deeply about the implications of the quantum theory, but I have not been able to find any information about his views on the implications of the theory in later years. So I was wondering if anyone can point me to some resources.

Comment: Russell did not write anything on quantum theory in later years, and was generally out of touch with new developments in physics. What he did write on philosophy on time in 1936, for example, was an outgrowth of his pre-quantum musings and rather out of date, see [Bostock](https://academic.oup.com/philmat/article-abstract/18/1/1/1482345). In particular, Russell did not engage the "new" quantum mechanics after 1927 and likely was unfamiliar with it. His focus in late years shifted to social activism.

Comment: You can see Bertrand Russell, The Analysis of Matter (1927, Routledge), **Ch.4 The Theory of Quanta**. As you can see, BR's book has been published in 1927.